# How to decrease memory use when creating a numpy array of 3,000+ jpegs python3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I am trying to batch convert 3,000+ jpegs to numpy arrays for processing. 
I am running this on a MacBook Pro 2016 model with 8 gigabytes of RAM. 
After my program converts about 2,800 jpegs to numpy arrays and appends it to my img list my computer gives me a warning about maximum memory limit reached and I have to force quit python because it becomes unresponsive.

My code is below:

```
root_dir = '/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/data'
imgs = []
labels = []

all_img_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '*/*.jpg'))
np.random.shuffle(all_img_paths)
count = 0
for img_path in all_img_paths:
    count += 1
    img = io.imread(img_path)
    label = get_class(img_path)
    imgs.append(img)
    labels.append(label)

X = np.array(imgs, dtype='float32')
# Make one hot targets
Y = np.eye(2, dtype='uint8')[labels]
```

How can I reduce the amount of memory that this program requires and allow it to run with only 8 gigabytes of RAM?

Comment: why do you need an array of 3k jpg's? can you break it up into chunks? process 500 at a time or something. this seems like the easiest way to me, but maybe can't work with what you're trying to do

Comment: If your color depth is 8 bits, you could ensure that your images are stored as `numpy.uint8`arrays. Otherwise there are not that much to do. Do you really need to read all 3000 images at once. Isn't it possible to divide it down to chunks of a few hundred images?

Comment: Eventually, I'll need to recombine all of the chunks into one array so I can convert it to a one-hot target for keras. How can I ensure that my images are stored as numpy.uint8 arrays?

Comment: Okay so I have an idea on how to solve the issue, I can pre allocate a numpy array of size n and then just set the values of the array as I create them. This way, the computer doesn't have to find a new place in RAM to put the numpy array and it doesn't have to swap memory.

Comment: If you're running out of memory on the chunks, you'll certainly run out of memory on the full array.  You may be able to use `np.memmap` and keep the array on disk, but if you need to do calculations on the full array you'll still need it to fit in RAM.  You can't process in chunks somehow?

Comment: How would processing it in batches of 500 conserve RAM if in the end I need to combine all of the batches into one numpy array?

Comment: Well, we're assuming processing the batches would make a smaller array.  That's usually the point of processing - turning big data into smaller data.  What process are you planning to use for your classification?  Most of them have a `partial_fit` method that lets you process in batches.

Comment: From keras Docs: [How can I use Keras with datasets that don't fit in memory?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory).  Sorry, not a keras expert.  `partial_fit` is the `sklearn` method

Comment: 3000 samples (images) are actually not that much for machine learning and may well fit in memory. Chances are the images are bigger than they need to be. You can try to downscale them.

Comment: Extactly, the images are actually 1500 by 3500. I am going to downscale them to 375 by 875.